# PHP image output of a static image seems to be smaller than the static image itself, How?

Tags: php, image-processing, gd

I have created images using PHP image GD library and have them stored on my server, For the purpose of keeping some images uncached I wrote php code to fetch some specific images and output the php page as image through php headers:

```
$image=imagecreatefrompng($image_location);
header("Content-Type: image/png");
imagepng($image);
imagedestroy($image);
```

surprisingly, the image from php page is always slightly smaller in size than the original static file using which the image was created. Original PNG file was 11.5KB in one case, while the php png file of the same static file was 11.3KB

The original png image was created using

```
imagecreate(), imagecolorallocate(), imagettftext()
```

and

```
imagepng($image,$location,9,PNG_ALL_FILTERS)
```

Why is the original image itself always bigger than the original? How can I reduce the size first time itself? Is there something "un-optimized" about my code?

Please help me out, even a 10% saving on size will help me hugely.

Comment: _"smaller in size"_ pixels or bytes? A JPEG version of a PNG will typically be smaller in filesize (bytes) due to JPEG's lossy compression

Comment: smaller in size, both png files

Comment: You realise I still have no idea if you mean pixel dimensions or filesize, right? Also, you're using `imagejpeg()` so not _"both png files"_

Comment: my bad, it is the file size, I corrected functions to reflect png (I use if else condition so that it works for both png and jpeg, had pasted wrong part of code)